# How do you strip whitespace from an array using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I strip white space from an array using PHP?

Comment: You mean strip elements that are just whitespace or strip whitespace from all elements?

Answer (score 54):

You can use a combination of

- [`array_filter` — Filters elements of an array using a callback function](http://php.net/array_filter)
- [`array_map` — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays](http://php.net/array_map)
- [`trim` — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string](http://php.net/trim)

**Code:**

```
array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
```

This will remove all whitespace from the sides (but not between chars). And it will remove any entries of [input equal to FALSE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (e.g. 0, 0.00, null, false, …)

**Example:**

```
$array = array(' foo ', 'bar ', ' baz', '    ', '', 'foo bar');
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $array));
print_r($array);

// Output
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => baz
    [5] => foo bar
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, so I will try to cover almost all cases.

In general, you need to create a function which will do what you need, be it removing the spaces from the left and right of each element or remove the whitespace characters completely. Here's how:

```
<?php

function stripper($element)
{
    return trim($element); // this will remove the whitespace
                           // from the beginning and the end
                           // of the element
}

$myarray = array(" apple", "orange ", " banana ");
$stripped = array_map("stripper", $myarray);
var_dump($stripped);

?>
```

```
Result:

Array
(
    [0] => "apple"
    [1] => "orange"
    [2] => "banana"
)
```

You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = $_REQUEST['jform']['name_cat'];
$input = str_replace(" ","",$subject);
```