# Remove array elements which contain only whitespaces?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, whitespace

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [
   'red',
   '   ',
   'blue',
   '       ',
   'green',
   '  ',
   'white',
   '    ',
   'black',
   '           '
];
```

I'm trying to remove all items which are just containing whitespace(s).

This is the expected result:

```
[
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'white',
    'black'
]
```

I can do that if those whitespaces item be empty. So I can use `$arr = array_filter($arr);`. But in this case, because there are whitespaces instead of nothing, `array_filter()` isn't useful. Is there any approach to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384058/how-do-you-strip-whitespace-from-an-array-using-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just couple it with `array_map` using `trim`:

```
$arr = array_filter(array_map('trim', $arr));
```

This doesn't reindex the keys though, if you want you could just use `array_values`:

```
$arr = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $arr)));
```

Comment: Both of these snippets mutate the data as a side effect of filtering.

Answer (score 2):

array_filter takes a callback function. You can do whatever you want.

```
array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
    return trim($v) !== '';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

hth

Comment: There is no point in adding access to the array keys if you aren't going to do anything with them.

Comment: You are welcome.  The age of a post never matters when demonstrating best practices to researchers.

Answer (score 0):

The described task is not at all about "trimming"; it is about removing elements which contain only spaces.

I'll extend the sample data to expose potential differences between my advice which does not mutate the original values while filtering versus earlier posted answers.

```
$array = [
    'red',
    '   ',
    'blue',
    '       ',
    '',
    'green  ',
    '  ',
    'white',
    '    ',
    'black',
    '           ',
];
```

Non-regex for determining strings which are not all spaces.

```
var_export(
    array_filter($array, fn($v) => !ctype_space($v))
);
```

A regex which actually removes all elements comprised exclusively of one or more whitespace characters (including tabs, new lines, etc).

```
var_export(
    preg_grep('/^\s+$/', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT)
);
```

Both output: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/r08CN))

```
array (
  0 => 'red',
  2 => 'blue',
  4 => '',
  5 => 'green  ',
  7 => 'white',
  9 => 'black',
)
```

Using the default behavior of `array_filter()` after trimming (as shown in Kevin's answer) risks mutating the original values as well as removing falsey values -- like zero.